# dmenu doesn't set environment variable as per my .bash_profile when running Emacs

Tags: emacs, bashrc, dwm

I have following ~/.bash_profile

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

and ~/.bashrc

```
### Check for shell interactivity.

if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
    return
fi

### Nyan-cat prompt.

PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[35m\]^_^\[\e[0m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]O_O\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \$ "

### PATH

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

So when I run emacs from terminal all OK. When I start it with `dmenu` (getenv "PATH") and `exec-path` variable doesn't contain `~/bin` directory.

When I do it in xfce with `xfrun4` command with same bash configuration all seams to work too.

What is the problem with dmenu?

Comment: This question needs a bit of work ... very confusing. Anyway, I would take a look at the dmenu documentation since you can run emacs fine in other ways. Perhaps dmenu doesn't run the bash config files by default?

Comment: Or perhaps it loads configuration once (at startup fo sorts) and you updated your profile afterwards?

Comment: No, my configuration doesn't change after I run dwm session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem with editing my `~/.xsession` file. Add following to it before running dwm.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Now you can remove same lines from you `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

TERM=dumb in emacs shell so it never gets past the interactive test at the top of your .bashrc .bash_profile is not run in emacs either.

Try moving the stuff you think is safe to run in non-interactive mode (think environment variables that won't affect rsync, git, remote ssh command, cron jobs, etc.) to above the test for interactive mode where it returns at the top of the script.

Comment: `M-x shell` run fine. But if I call `compile` or `comint` commands, then environment doesn't work with `~/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Evidentally, dmenu isn't a login shell, and so things in your .bashrc aren't run. Generally this is good as that could slow it down, or create interesting behavior if you're not careful with checking for interactive vs non-interactive sessions.

So which rc files are run before dmenu starts something? [It will depend a little on how your OS is set up.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281923) In essence there are a couple files you might think to try:

- `.profile`
- `.bash_profile`
- `.xprofile`
- `.xinitrc`
- `.xsession`
- `.xsessionrc`

I haven't tried all of these, but for me, running i3wm from a tty login, .xinitrc works because that is run after `startx` in my `.bash_profile`, and I can put anything I want added to my environment before running `exec i3` at the end; i.e., anything in my `.xinitrc` is run before starting my graphic session.

For many users with a graphic session manager for their login screen, I think that `.xsession` might be a better place. You might have to try a couple of the different files I listed, but you should be able to find one that works.

(For those interested, this is how I solve disappearing icons in KDE programs run not in KDE: After setting a theme, it can be specified in `.xinitrc`, e.g., `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`).